# no WiFi -- network UNCLAIMED for Intel network controller

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, intel-wireless

I installed xubuntu 16.04.3 LTS on my fairly new MSI GL62M 7RD-058 laptop and Ethernet connection works, but not WiFi.

`lshw -C network` outputs:

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:df200000-df201fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 10
       serial: 4c:cc:6a:84:b8:0a
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=10.20.21.23 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:128 memory:df100000-df13ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
```

`iwconfig` ouputs:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
enp3s0    no wireless extensions.
```

How do I fix this?  I am upgraded to the latest version and updated. From reading other sources, I suspect there is either a missing driver or a driver conflict, but I am inexperienced.

EDITS: Output of `lspci -nn | grep 0280`:

`02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10)`

Output of `uname -r`:

`4.4.0-98-generic`

Comment: May we also see the result of: `lspci -nn | grep 0280` and also: `uname -r` ?

Comment: Yes!  Added to question.

Comment: Please notice that you have the same 8086:24fb device.

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: I ran the suggested commands on that post and upon rebooting, I get a softlock.

Comment: Any clues on the screen? Can you try rebooting again? Can you interrupt the boot process at the GRUB menu and select the older 4.4.0-98 kernel version?